Can alternative energy concepts improve bounds on large values of Dirichlet polynomials?
In the recent paper "New large value estimates for Dirichlet polynomials" by Guth and Maynard, the authors use the concept of additive energy to derive improved bounds for large values of Dirichlet polynomials. Their main result (Theorem 1.1) gives the bound:
$$ R \leq T^{o(1)}(N^2 V^{-2} + N^{18/5} V^{-4} + T N^{12/5} V^{-4}) $$
for the number of points $R$ where a Dirichlet polynomial of length $N$ takes values of size $V$. The authors note that the critical case occurs when $N = T^{4/5}$, $|W| = T^{3/5}$, and $E(W) \approx |W|^{5/2} \approx |W|^4 / T$, where $W$ is the set of points where the Dirichlet polynomial is large and $E(W)$ is its additive energy.
My question is whether other energy-like concepts from additive combinatorics could potentially lead to further improvements, especially in this critical range. Could the multiplicative energy of $W$ provide additional useful information? Might the doubling constant or Freiman dimension of $W$ offer insights that could tighten the bounds? Or maybe even a totally new definition of energy that could be some type of "weighted average" of the existing energies definitions. Is there a way to leverage the concept of approximate groups to better understand the structure of $W$ and improve the estimates?
Furthermore, I'm curious if analyzing the sumset or product set properties of $W$ could lead to stronger results. Are there other energy-like measures in additive combinatorics that might be particularly well-suited to this problem? I'm especially interested in whether any of these concepts could help reduce the exponent $18/5$ in the $N^{18/5} V^{-4}$ term, or if they might suggest new approaches to the problem.
Finally, would "polymath" type projects help improve these bounds? Are these type of projects still occurring and if so, do you think they could help in this particular case?

A very similar question was asked recently, although it appears to have since been deleted. There @TerryTao pointed out that James Maynard addressed this in a Q&A session of a recent talk at IAS about the paper. In short, Maynard and Guth thought about this and it isn't clear if this is possible. See: https://youtu.be/dIe5hqTuB4k?si=oNtLRCyQ2Kx5x0TD&t=4235

@MarkLewko That question was probably AI generated.

@MarkLewko: Thank you. Do you think polymath type projects would help in this case?

Found the other question (which might only be visible to those with enough reputation): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/472887/additive-energy-of-large-values-of-dirichlet-polynomials

@CicadaBarryKate: My general sense is that the number of researchers with the expertise and inclination to work on a polymath project on this problem is much smaller than other problems that have been the subject of popular and successful projects. That said, I don't want to discourage anyone. This is an exciting development in an area that has been stuck for quite a while. I hope there is further progress, be it from a polymath project or more traditional research efforts.
